# How can I hide the source code of a nodeJS solution built with Electron (asar files)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I look for the best way to hide the code of a solution built with Electron.

Any ideas?

To build the solution with Electron having **asar files is not enough**. I really need to hide the code so it should not be easy to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

There are some possibilities. Take a look at https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/closurebuilder. It produces a Java' compiled output content (.jar). Then, you can use a jar module for Node.JS in order to access the internal content (like https://www.npmjs.com/package/jarfile).

Comment: Make sure you add the core concepts and code from the links, as they (the links) can become obsolete over time.

Comment: This is entirely wrong. Closure compiler generates a minified and optimized .js file that can be loaded in the browser with all Closure Library files that are required by your code bundled with it so you can load a single .js file.