# I want to hide my Webapp source code fron local host

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

I have made a project of library management webapp for  collage  . it will  host it on the local server of the college and I want to hide its source code

Comment: What do you mean with `hiding its source code`?

Comment: Yes i want to share my project to college and they run it at there own server and at the same time I want that collage doesn't see my source code

Comment: See if these can help - [How to make exe files from a node.js app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8173232/8244632). [How to make exe file from Reactjs and a nodejs app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56064318/8244632) and [Compiling a Node.js Application into an .exe File](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/compile-your-nodejs-application-into-a-exe-file/).

Comment: If they have acces to the internal server they will be able to see it. You can't hide it at all.  Someone who doesn't have acces to the internal server won't be able to see it. Anyway see [How can I hide the source code of a nodeJS solution built with Electron (asar files)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33944950/18309173) or @LalitFauzdar's answer links.

Comment: do i have any other option

Comment: Do you want to hide the frontend part? How is your backend code accessible?